# Generic T from parameters instead of manually specifying

Tags: c#, generics

I wrote this class:

```
public class ResultsPair<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public ResultsItem Result { get; set; }

    public ResultsPair(ResultsItem result, T value)
    {
        Result = result;
        Value = value;
    }

    public static ResultsPair<T> Create(ResultsItem result, T value)
    {
        return new ResultsPair<T>(result, value);
    }

    public static ResultsPair<T> CreateSuccess(T value) => Create(ResultsItem.Success(string.Empty), value);
    public static ResultsPair<T> CreateError(ResultsItem result) => Create(result, default(T));
}
```

To call it, I would do these:

```
ResultsPair<User>.CreateSuccess(newUser);
ResultsPair<User>.CreateError(ResultsItem.Error("A server connection error has occured."));
```

On the first one, newUser is type User, so I do not want to manually define it again using < User >.

On the CreateError, I have no problem defining manually the T class, since it won't know it by default.

On just the Create method, I need to do this `ResultsPair<User>.Create(ResultsItem, User)`. Which I don't like. `ResultsPair.Create(ResultsItem, User)` should be enough.

Is there a way to have it achieve what I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this by additionally creating a non-generic class `ResultsPair` with generic methods `Create`, `CreateSuccess` and `CreateError`:

```
public static class ResultsPair
{
    public static ResultsPair<T> CreateSuccess<T>(T value) => Create(ResultsItem.Success(string.Empty), value);
    public static ResultsPair<T> CreateError<T>(ResultsItem result) => Create(result, default(T));

    public static ResultsPair<T> Create<T>(ResultsItem result, T value)
    {
        return new ResultsPair<T>(result, value);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ResultsPair.CreateSuccess(newUser);
ResultsPair.CreateError<User>(ResultsItem.Error("A server connection error has occured."));
ResultsPair.Create(ResultsItem, User)
```

---

Just to clarify: Your complete code would look like this:

```
public class ResultsPair<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public ResultsItem Result { get; set; }

    public ResultsPair(ResultsItem result, T value)
    {
        Result = result;
        Value = value;
    }
}

public static class ResultsPair
{
    public static ResultsPair<T> CreateSuccess<T>(T value) => Create(ResultsItem.Success(string.Empty), value);
    public static ResultsPair<T> CreateError<T>(ResultsItem result) => Create(result, default(T));

    public static ResultsPair<T> Create<T>(ResultsItem result, T value)
    {
        return new ResultsPair<T>(result, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have also been trying that code, but when I use it in my class, I get this error. Type parameter 'T' has the same name as the type parameter from outer type 'ResultsPair<T>'

Comment: I think you have simply made the `CreateSuccess` and `CreateError` methods generic, without putting them in a NEW, non-generic class

Comment: You are exactly right. Sorry about that sir. I will accept this answer when I'm allowed to (i think in 2 days).

Comment: @DanielHilgarth You should move the `Create` also to the new type. – Basically, OP’s original static methods can all be moved there without changing them apart from making them generic.

Comment: @poke: I think that is a matter of preference. But I agree. I would have moved it as well.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth OP wants to be able to do `ResultsPair.Create(resultItem, user)` too though. So it’s not exactly preference but required if you want the type inference to work there too.

Comment: @poke: Right. Missed that

Comment: @poke: Fixed. Thanks for the QA

Comment: @Fildor: It simply should be a static class. Fixed